# What's the difference between cahoots and collude

Tags: differences

They seem similar to me.

### [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com)

in cahoots

> If you say that one person is in cahoots with another, you do not trust the first person because you think that they are planning something secretly with the other.

collude

> If one person colludes with another, they co-operate with them secretly or illegally.

### [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/)

cahoots

> to be planning or doing something dishonest with somebody else

collude

> to work together secretly or illegally in order to trick other people
> collude (with somebody) (in something/in doing something) Several people had colluded in the murder.
> collude (with somebody) (to do something) They colluded with terrorists to overthrow the government.

### [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/)

cahoots

> secretly involved with someone in a dishonest activity or plan-

collude

> to work secretly with someone to do something dishonest

Comment: Uh, yeah, they're similar.  "In cahoots" is a bit more informal, and you'd rarely use "cahoots" by itself.  (There are these things known as synonyms.)

Comment: What do you mean by difference? One is a noun and the other a verb. They don't falute alike either.

Comment: It's _be in cahoots with_.

Comment: @tchrist If I say "I've been in cahoots with that person" and "I've colluded with that person", it doesn't matter if one is a noun and the other is a verb, because the noun is used as if it was a verb, as it usually is in most people's conversation when they use that word.

Comment: In your research, did you notice any words in the definitions like "informal"?

Comment: _Collude_ is an activity verb and usually takes the transitivizing preposition _with_, while _cahoots_ is a  noun appearing only in the idiom _be in cahoots with_, meaning 'colluding with'. Aside from those differences, _collude_ is in a higher register than _cahoots_. Also, being in cahoots with somebody is a relatively permanent relation, while collusion is often temporary.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm not sure I agree with your last point. I think they're both in relation to some particular activity. Would you object to saying that  Trump was in cahoots with the Russians (I'm not asking if you agree with the statement, just the form of it)?

Comment: Yes, but it may be just my own habit. Idioms mean what you intend for them to mean, just like words.